# AddThis Facebook like button inside TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, addthis, episerver-6-r2

I'm trying to use Addthis (http://www.addthis.com) script to place things like Facebook "Like" buttons on my pages. When I put the "Like" code in and save it TinyMCE strips part of the code out? For example. This is the Follow Us code.

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
</div>
```

After I save and check again the **fb:like:layout="button_count"** section is removed by TinyMCE.

**Note: I use TinyMCE within EpiServer CMS 6 R2**

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure tinymce not to stripout those attributes.
Have a look at the tinymce configuration parameter [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements).

Comment: Yes I have tried this  [TinyMCEPluginNonVisual(AlwaysEnabled = true,
        EditorInitConfigurationOptions = "{valid_elements: 'a[fb:like:layout=]'}")] 

But it did not help

Comment: hmm, i do not know if it is valid to put those ':' right there

Comment: I have tried putting "*" , then it allowed "fb:like", but it trimmed ":layout".

Comment: i do not know if the Serializer is able to understand complex expressions like this...but there should be asolution. I suggest you ask in the tinymce forum directly - with luck one of the developers will answer.

Comment: did not find anything at TinyMCE forum either, had to go with a jquery fix, to add the attribute dynamically